# Identify comic novel with mice and aliens (Martians?)

Tags: story-identification, comics

The story takes place on Mars (or another planet) where Martians (?) are waiting for people from Earth to land. Both planets have been communicating for some time and they finally manage to meet each other for the first time. They're very excited and happy about it. At the end, the reader discovers the "people" from Earth are mice and we see a mouse wearing an astronaut suit, shaking hand with a Martian. They're all smiling.

As far as I remember this comic novel is something like 2-5 five pages long, black and white. I read it about 25 years ago, but I guess it's older (50s? 60s?)

Comment: So, not Mickey then? http://www.spaceacts.com/starship/seh/micksafe.gif

Comment: No idea, but you reminded me [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/Biker_Mice_From_Mars_2006.jpg) exists so +1

Comment: Nope, no Mickey...